Moduli functor of semistable sheaves
I've been reading the construction and property of moduli functors of semistable sheaves, following Huybrechts and Lehn's book The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves. Although my questions are not highly related to each other, I would still like to put them under the same question, since they are too many. Let $X$ be a projective scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$, with a very ample line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Let $P\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be a fixed polynomial.
Firstly, why do we need boundedness? The definition of boundedness is the following: a family of isomorphism classes of coherent sheaves on $X$ is bounded if there is a $k$-scheme $S$ of finite type and a coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X\times S}$-module $F$ such that the family is contained in the set $\{F_s\mid s\text{ closed point of } S\}$. But for the moduli functor, given a scheme $S$ over $k$, we consider the set
\begin{equation*}
\{F\in \operatorname{Coh}(X_S)\mid F\text{ flat over }S, F_s\text{ semistable on }X_s,P(F_s) = P \}.
\end{equation*}
So we consider a family of sheaves $F_s$ on different schemes $X_s$, which is not related to boundedness at all.
Secondly, why do we need the category $\operatorname{Coh}_{d,d'}(X)$ and the stability condition defined on it (cf. Section 1.6)? Other than it is a generalization of $\mu$-stability, I don't see the importance of these new notions.
Thirdly, when we use valuative criterion for properness to prove Langton's result (which will prove the properness of the moduli space) (cf. Section 2.B), why can we assume that residue field of the discrete valuation ring is just the field $k$? Is it because the morphism $\mathcal{M}\rightarrow k$ has target $k$, so we have a stronger version of valuative criterion than the usual one?
Finally, why do we have inequality (3.2) in the proof of Lemma 3.3.2?
Thanks for any help.
